# I am trying pascals triangle using perl.I am getting bit different output.Could somebody please point out what is the error?

Tags: perl, loops

My program is -

```
@arr=('1','1  1');
print "enter the number of rows\n";
$rows=<STDIN>;
$v=0;
while($v<$rows)
{
     foreach $ele (@arr)
        {
          @arr1=split(/\s+/,$ele);
          $g=@arr1;
          #print "$g\n";
          $i=0;
          $j=1;
          $str='';
          while ($j<$g)
             {
                $res=$arr1[$i]+$arr1[$j];
                #print "$res\n";
                $i=$1+1;
                $j=$j+1;
                $str=$str.' '.$res;

            }

        $final='1'.' '.$str.' '.'1';
        print "$final\n";


}
$v=$v+1;
#@arr=();
push(@arr,$final);
}

print "@arr";

foreach (@arr)
{

    print "$_\n";
}
```

my output is:

```
C:\Perl\bin>perl pascal.pl
enter the number of rows
4
1
1  1
1  2 1
1  3 3 1
1  4 6 4 1
1  5 10 8 5 1
```

The 8 on the last line should be 10. But why it is coming 8?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is here:

```
$i=$1+1;
```

You wanted to use `$i` instead of `$1`.

You should use [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings), they would've told you.

Answer (score 1):

I had done one typo error .Instead of $i=$i+1 ,I had $i=$1+1.